# Canon MP630 M/F printer wont print correctly

Tags: printing, canon

In Ubuntu 11.10, the MP630 seems to install correctly but when printing, it prints double height characters with blank lines through them, on a very simple text(e.g.  in gedit). It also does crazy line feeds and scatters characters over the page.

I have tried using the .deb files that I have used previously and successfully in a number of previous distributions of Ubuntu but I keep getting dependency issues with `libcupsys2` and `libcups2`.

I have tried changing the dependencies in c`nijfilter-common_3.00-1_i386.deb.org` and `cnijfilter-mp630series_3.00-1_i386.deb`.

Running `libcupsys2_1.3.9-17ubuntu3.1_all.deb` but then indicates that I'll break the libcups2 package. I get the error message:

`Breaks existing package 'libcups2' conflict: libcupsys2 ( )`

As I consider myself as still in the learning stage please advise of anything I may have overlooked.

Answer (score 1):

Update: I have found a (temporary) solution at the following link: http://bkintegration.com/2011/05/mp-620-630-debian-based-univeral-installer/ . Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

This is a follow-up on the link provided in the previous answer.

I've recently inherited a Canon PIXMA MP620 series printer/scanner and was a bit perplexed by the number of convoluted recommendations for installing drivers floating around the Internet.

The instructions provided [here](http://rackerua.com/2011/05/mp-620-630-debian-based-univeral-installer/) worked successfully. This driver is intended for both the 620 and 630 series printers.

Additional instructions can be seen at the driver maintainer's site: https://github.com/cloudnull/MP620-630-Linux-Printer.

After installation, I am able to successfully:

- print (both simplex and duplex)
- scan
- control local access
- modify resolution, border parameters, and toner densities

Here are the instructions to install the drivers:

1. From a terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>t</kbd>), run the following commands:

   - `cd Downloads`
   - `git clone git://github.com/cloudnull/MP620-630-Linux-Printer.git`
   - `cd MP620-630-Linux-Printer/`
   - `sudo su`
   - `sudo chmod +x install.sh` (Most likely, these permissions are already at the appropriate level)
   - `./install.sh`
2. During the installation procedure, you will be prompted for the IP address of the printer(this is not needed if the printer is DHCP enabled).